# merging pdf using java method and getting error

Tags: java, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have a piece of code which is creating a problem. The following code which i am using for merging is the below:

```
<cfset inFiles = [#convertArray#]>
<cfset outFile = "c:\merged_1.pdf">
<cfscript>
try {
    outStream = createObject("java", "java.io.FileOutputStream").init( outFile );
    copy = createObject("java", "com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfCopyFields").init(outStream);
    PdfReader = createObject("java", "com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader");
    for (inFile in inFiles) {
        reader = PdfReader.init( inFile );
        copy.addDocument(reader);
        //writedump(inFile);
    }
    WriteOutput("Finished!");
}
catch (java.language.Exception de) {
    writedump(de);
}
if (IsDefined("copy")) {
    copy.close();
}
if (IsDefined("outputStream")) {
    outputStream.close();
}
</cfscript>
```

convertArray is the list of files like this

```
"C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\wwwroot\_pdf\YEF5.pdf","C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\wwwroot\_pdf\WEX9.pdf","C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\wwwroot\_pdf\1WFX8.pdf","C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\wwwroot\_pdf\WFY6.pdf","C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\wwwroot\_pdf\1WFZ3.pdf"
```

if i pass the hard coded values it works, but if i send it as `convertArray` it throws following error

```
The web site you are accessing has experienced an unexpected error.
Please contact the website administrator. 

The following information is meant for the website developer for debugging purposes.
Error Occurred While Processing Request
"C:/ColdFusion10/cfusion/wwwroot/_pdf/YEF5.pdf","C:/ColdFusion10/cfusion/wwwroot/_pdf/0WEX9.pdf","C:/ColdFusion10/cfusion/wwwroot/_pdf/1WFX8.pdf","C:/ColdFusion10/cfusion/wwwroot/_pdf/1WFY6.pdf","C:/ColdFusion10/cfusion/wwwroot/_pdf/1WFZ3.pdf" not found as file or resource.


The error occurred in C:/ColdFusion10/cfusion/wwwroot/index.cfm: line 30
28 :    PdfReader = createObject("java", "com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader");
29 :    for (inFile in inFiles) {
30 :        reader = PdfReader.init( inFile );
31 :        copy.addDocument(reader);
32 :        //writedump(inFile);
```

stack trace error

```
java.io.IOException: "C:/ColdFusion10/cfusion/wwwroot/_pdf/YEF5.pdf","C:/ColdFusion10/cfusion/wwwroot/_pdf/1WEX9.pdf","C:/ColdFusion10/cfusion/wwwroot/_pdf/1WFX8.pdf","C:/ColdFusion10/cfusion/wwwroot/_pdf/1WFY6.pdf","C:/ColdFusion10/cfusion/wwwroot/_pdf/1WFZ3.pdf" not found as file or resource.
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PRTokeniser.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at coldfusion.runtime.java.JavaProxy.CreateObject(JavaProxy.java:166)
    at coldfusion.runtime.java.JavaProxy.invoke(JavaProxy.java:80)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:2428)
    at cfindex2ecfm33320163.runPage(C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\wwwroot\index.cfm:30)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:244)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:446)
    at coldfusion.filter.CfincludeFilter.invoke(CfincludeFilter.java:65)
    at coldfusion.filter.IpFilter.invoke(IpFilter.java:64)
    at coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:451)
    at coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:48)
    at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40)
    at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:112)
    at coldfusion.filter.LicenseFilter.invoke(LicenseFilter.java:30)
    at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:94)
    at coldfusion.filter.BrowserDebugFilter.invoke(BrowserDebugFilter.java:79)
    at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
    at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:58)
    at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
    at coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:62)
    at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:219)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:450)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: *throws following error*  That is just a generic header. The real cause is in the stack trace message.

Comment: i updated my question by adding the stack trace informatio of what i have

Answer (score 0):

If you review the stack trace message, it indicates the supplied path string is invalid:

> java.io.IOException:
>   "C:/ColdFusion10/cfusion/wwwroot/_pdf/YEF5.pdf","C:/ColdFusion10/cfusion/wwwroot/_pdf/1WEX9.pdf","C:/ColdFusion10/cfusion/wwwroot/_pdf/1WFX8.pdf","C:/ColdFusion10/cfusion/wwwroot/_pdf/1WFY6.pdf","C:/ColdFusion10/cfusion/wwwroot/_pdf/1WFZ3.pdf"
>   **not found as file or resource**

From the values in the error message, you are passing in a string containing *multiple* file paths, when a *single* path is expected instead. If the `convertArray` variable contains a list of paths, use the `ListToArray` function to convert it into an array. As long as each element contains a *single* (valid) file path, the code will work fine.

If you are still getting a *"not found as file or resource"* error, that means the path(s) are invalid or inaccessible. Add some debugging so you can see the actual file paths and verify they are valid files:

```
<cfscript>
    // convert list of files into array
    convertArray = "c:/path/FirstFile.pdf,c:/otherpath/SecondFile.pdf";
    inFiles = listToArray(convertArray);
    outFile = "c:\temp\merged_1.pdf";

    try {
        // ... 
        for (inFile in inFiles) {

            // Verify current value is valid file path
            writeOutput("<br>DEBUG: Current Path: "& inFile );
            writeOutput(" FileExists("& FileExists(inFile) &")");

            // ... initialize reader and copy file 
        }
    }
    // ...etcetera
</cfscript>
```

Comment: same issue even i tried with your code too, but same issue it is throwing

Comment: Well the error is saying the path(s) are invalid, or possibly inaccessible. Start by dumping the value of `inFile` inside the loop. What is the value? Also, use `FileExists(inFile)` to verify the path really exists.